# Ruby On Rails With MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this problem ROR with MySQL, what may the problem?

[image]

I instaled mysql2 and now error is:
[image]

Comment: What the problem In My Quetion?

Comment: If I had to guess I would say people are -1 you because your question does not show research effort :)

Comment: that and the error message tells you exactly what to do

Answer (score 2):

First do this:

```
gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include"'
```

Then:

```
bundle config build.mysql2 '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include"'
```

Your path may vary please check that first.

In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

Then via commandline:

```
bundle install
```

Comment: I Instaled mysql not mysql2 those are same?

Comment: Yea it's some kind of slow compared to the new one. Still worth a shoot to try the version 2 in your rails app.

Comment: I instaled mysql2 and add in Gemfile mysql2 and the error changes see above I edited my question

Comment: Have you installed rails via the rails installer? Do you have mysql-server installed?

Comment: i have mysql server instaled it runs, i use phpmyadmin for web interface, yes i instaled rails with railsinstaler. I don know what the problem :(